# What is a good source for geometric algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I am looking for any good sources for geometric algorithms specifically;

The simple stuff like when two lines cross and so on is easy enough (and easy to find), but I would like to find somewhere with algorithms for the more tricky things, such as finding the shape formed by expanding a given polygon by some amount; fast algorithms for shapes with curved sides, etc.

Any good tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I did find exactly what I was looking for: [Real-Time Collision Detection](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/) by Christer Ericson. This is wonderful, and I recommend it strongly. Not so much on curved sides etc, but for the essential stuff on how to actually program geometrical hit testing and so on properly, it seems hard to beat.

Answer (score 6):

[Computational Geometry Algorithms Library](http://www.cgal.org/) is decent.

Comment: It is, but only for complex algorithms. It's complex itself and its usage for simple things is not recommended.

Answer (score 6):

I enjoy [Dave Eberly's website](http://www.geometrictools.com/), especially some of his PDFs.

For curved surfaces, there's a pretty [good free textbook here](http://tom.cs.byu.edu/~557/), that covers beziers, nurbs and subdivision surfaces.

Answer (score 6):

["Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/978-3-540-77973-5) by Mark de Berg, Otfried Cheong, Marc van Kreveld, and Mark Overmars is an excellent introductory computational geometry textbook.  It is known as "the four-Marks book" even though only three of the four authors are named Mark or Marc.

Answer (score 3):

The definitive sourcebook for this is *Mathematical Elements for Computer Graphics* by Rogers and Adams

http://www.nar-associates.com/nar-publishing/mecg2nd.htm

Comment: Is "Procedural Elements of Computer Graphics" basically the same book, updated, or is it different? Which is better from an algorithms point of view?

Comment: OK, I have now seen that this is a different book, apparently less algorithmic.

Answer (score 2):

[computational geometry in c](http://books.google.com/books?id=gsv7HALW2jYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=computational+geometry+in+c&sig=ACfU3U2rN16it8Bl_GmU5cdML4fqqYp99w) is a great book, i learnt a lot from it

Answer (score 2):

A very nice source of inspiration is Paul Bourke.
http://paulbourke.net/

straight to his geometry stuff : http://paulbourke.net/geometry/index.html

You might want to wander around on his site a bit, there's tons of nice stuff !

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten good use from the generically named [Computer Graphics, C Version](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135309247) by Hearn and Baker.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in something realy complex, try searching it on a http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/ It's a scientific digital library, and the computational geometry is well presented there. I used it a lot while implementing shadows in a 3D.