# how to correctly orient grid coordinates

Tags: java, sorting

I am ingesting four grid coordinates in decimal degrees similar to:  33.829785,-84.3958, so that I can draw a square on a map.  However, sometimes the coordinates are not passed in the correct sequence, which results in a triangle with an outlying point.  In researching this, I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/126658/906048) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/745048/906048) on S.O.  I've also looked into [Jgraph](http://www.jgraph.com/), [Jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) and [Grappa](http://www2.research.att.com/~john/Grappa/); but these frameworks are suited more to creating an manipulating graphs, rather than evaluating them.  I have also found the following code, which works for sorting a set of four integer points, but not for decimal degrees, because of the restrictions imposed by the java.lang.comparable interface.

```
int[][] array={{2,2},{1,1},{4,3},{2,1},{10,1}};
            Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<int[]>(){
                    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b){
                            //assumes array length is 2
                            int x,y;
                            if (a[0]!=b[0]) {
                                    x=a[0];y=b[0];
                            }
                            else{
                                    x=a[1];y=b[1];
                            }
                            if (x<y) return -1;
                            else if (x==y) return 0;
                            else return +1;
                    }
            });
            for(int[] term: array){
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(term));
            }
```

Comment: What are the restrictions on comparable you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted should work, once you've converted it to work with `double`. I'm not sure why you think it wouldn't.

Don't get confused by the return type of `compare`, that needs to stay `int`. All other references to `int` become double. This might help: [Comparator with double type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242023/comparator-with-double-type)

Good luck!